# Dilemma of setting a timeout in ZeroMQ

Tags: java, zeromq

I currently use ZeroMQ with Java binding. My program is in a `PUB/SUB` mode. 
It seems reasonable to set a timeout, while a client can't receive a message from `PUB`-side.

But for the publish server, who sends messages without a fixed frequency, it's hard to decide a reasonable timeout.

On the other hand, if no timeout is set, then a program would probably stuck at function:

```
recv()
```

forever even publish server is dead.

If there a good solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, there is a good solution or two:

A principally best solution is to use a **`Poller`** instance, for which a `.poll()` method tells your code, again with a help of an explicitly configurable `aTimeOut` in [ms], whether there is any incoming message to either attempt a non-blocking `.recv()` method or not even trying to do so, once there is NACK for any such message being present from the call to a `.poll()` method ( for details check the API ).

Another way is to use a non-blocking mode of a call to the `.recv( aSockINST, ZMQ_DONTWAIT )` method. Here, the API + wrapper / binding, specify how it  handles a state, where none such message was locally ready to get `.recv()`-ed, so that one may rely on the common language's available syntax-scaffolding - like `{ try: except: finally: }` or `{ try: catch: }` or `{ defer; panic(); recover() }` - to handle either of the return states from the `.recv( .., ZMQ_DONTWAIT )` call. Similar rules apply to an ( almost ) blocking call, with some moderately small `.recv()` timeout.

Comment: You save me again! Thanks a lot! And I'm still a little confuse about the difference between using poll & .recv .....
It seems that "poll" is another .recv, it's just another .recv without timeout!? Using "poll" just let program stuck at "poll" instead of ".recv"!?
What do I miss here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pollers:

```
poller = zmq.Poller()
poller.register(client_receiver, zmq.POLLIN);
```

for further reading:
http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/multisocket/zmqpoller.html

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Honestly I'm still confusing about the usage of "poll".... 
I might use ".recv" with short timeout then check the receiving data to avoid sticking progarm